# Make view scroll with RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

If the content of my vertical recyclerview (which consists of CardViews) exceeds the screen, one can scroll to see the content, which is located below the boundaries of the screen. I want to somehow attach an ImageView to the RecyclerView, so that when the RecyclerView content is exceeding the screen, scrolling does not only scroll down the CardViews within the RecyclerView, but also the ImageView located directly above the first card.
At the moment, when i scroll down the RecyclerView, the ImageView stays fixed above the RecyclerView, independent of the scrolling.
So how do I scroll down the ImageView as if it was the first CardView in my RecyclerView? 
**EDIT:**
Unscrolled: 
[Unscrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk3z6.png)

Scrolled the way it currently does, but I want the (+) ImageView to scroll with the cards:
[Scrolled the way it currently does, but I want the (+) ImageView to scroll with the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAVUw.png)

Comment: Maybe you can provide some photo.